# How to know the number of vertices encountered while traversing from one vertex to another in gremlin

Tags: graph-theory, gremlin, tinkerpop3

[image]

In the above picture we can see that , I can traverse to node **5** from both node **1** and **2** , but while traversing from **1** only one vertex in encountered which is **3** but for two it is **5** and **4** .

How can I write a gremlin query , that will return the number of vertex encountered .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions about Gremlin a picture can be helpful, but it is far more important to provide a Gremlin script that creates some sample data - like this:

```
g.addV().property(id,1).as('1').
  addV().property(id,2).as('2').
  addV().property(id,3).as('3').
  addV().property(id,4).as('4').
  addV().property(id,5).as('5').
  addE('link').from('1').to('3').
  addE('link').from('2').to('3').
  addE('link').from('2').to('4').
  addE('link').from('3').to('5').
  addE('link').from('4').to('5').iterate()
```

In answer to your question, I think you just need to use `path()` step to show where Gremlin has traversed:

```
gremlin> g.V().repeat(out()).emit().path()
==>[v[1],v[3]]
==>[v[1],v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[2],v[3]]
==>[v[2],v[4]]
==>[v[2],v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[2],v[4],v[5]]
==>[v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[4],v[5]]
```

If you're just interested in paths between vertices 1/2 and 5 then you can add some restrictions:

```
gremlin> g.V(1,2).repeat(out()).emit(hasId(5)).path()
==>[v[1],v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[2],v[3],v[5]]
==>[v[2],v[4],v[5]]
```

Building on that further, if you want to count the vertices in the middle of the path, then you could `unfold()` the paths, filter away your start/end vertices and `count()`:

```
gremlin> g.V(2).
......1>   repeat(out()).
......2>     emit(hasId(5)).
......3>   path().
......4>   unfold().
......5>   not(hasId(2,5)).
......6>   dedup().
......7>   count()
==>2
```

Hopefully, that gives you some inspiration. There are a lot of nice examples of this in [Gremlin Recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#between-vertices).

Comment: Thanks for such quick response , it helped me a lot .  Next time if I ask any more gremlin related question , I will provide necessary gremlin script for sure . Have a nice day .